# jquery $.ajax get will fetch a file via http but fails when talking to server direct, X-Requested-With not being set correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble getting jquery (1.6.1) to talk to a local server (on same machine) even though as far as I can tell what the server is producing looks correct.

*as a test I put the server output in a file, and access it, it works:*

var url = "http://localhost/web-from-hols/viz/library/test4.json"

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        error: that.searchError,
        success: that.searchSuccess,
        complete: function(){dom.find('#loadingImg').hide();dom.find('.button').show();searching=false;}
            })
```

*but... point the url directly at the local server, and it fails, with status 0*

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"+key
```

*sniffing the http headers I see the following call and response,for the working...*

```
http://localhost/web-from-hols/viz/library/test4.json?_=1333363765977

GET /web-from-hols/viz/library/test4.json?_=1333363765977 HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate DNT: 1 Connection: keep-alive X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Referer: http://localhost/web-from-hols/viz/viz.html


HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 02 Apr 2012 10:49:25 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Apr 2012 02:28:15 GMT Etag: "42e020c-137f-4bca8f1467744" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 4991 Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: application/json
```

*and for the non working I see:*

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/EP1186609?_=1333370799152

GET /EP1186609?_=1333370799152 HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/web-from-hols/viz/viz.html
Origin: http://localhost


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 02 Apr 2012 02:33:43 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Mon, 02 Apr 2012 02:28:15 GMT
Etag: "42e020c-137f-4bca8f1467744"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4991
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

*the only real difference I can see is the working request includes*

```
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

*which is missing in the non working, although the non working has added:*

```
Origin: http://localhost
```

*I have tried to add this wit the code*

```
 $.ajaxSetup({ 
      headers: {"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"} 
    });
```

but this does not seem to help, rather than add the line

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

*I instead see the following added*

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-requested-with
```

Frankly I do not understand what's going on, I have read that jquery sometimes omits the 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" value when making request, or it might be a cross site issue, might.. :-(

This problem has been frustrating two of us for a day, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the url in the address bar? 127.0.0.1 or localhost?

Comment: It sounds like you're running up against the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), `127.0.0.1` is not the same as `localhost`.

Comment: You'd try first accesing the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/EP1186609` directly within your browser.

Comment: using the url directly in browser works fine, I am returned correct json content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send normal AJAX requests to another domain (even when that domain resolves to the same machine) or a different port. Firefox is trying to send a [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control) request, but then stops it after your server does not return the headers which signal that you allow CORS requests (such as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`).

Comment: thank you, adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in the return header does fix this. I am worried about security implication of that, which I do not understand, will read up on it.

Comment: Depending on what the AJAX call does, it might create a CSRF vulnerability. You can write a domain name instead of the `*`, that is reasonably secure. Keep in mind though that CORS is a relatively new feature, browser support is uneven (specifically, IE and Opera have very weak support - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors)).

Comment: hmm the server does not know the domain the request will come from, so  it cannot specify it in the header instead of *  On the plus side the server code is restricted to only accept one very limited input. Do not know if thats enough.